# Decode function in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone please explain the below SQL statement from Oracle DB:

```
select decode(TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')),'Monday','3','1') from dual
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, let's start with the `to_char`. `to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')` will give you the day of the week it is today. `to_char` lets you convert a date (in this case today's date since you've specified `sysdate`) into a string of a certain format. Take a look here for some other examples of date formats you can use:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

`trim` removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Now for the `decode`. You can think of `decode` like an if else statement. Take a look at:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php

In your particular example, you could read this statement as: if today is Monday return 3 else return 1.

`decode` also allows you to do things a bit more complex like this:

```
select decode(TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')),'Monday','3','Tuesday',5,'1') 
from dual
```

This would read: if today is Monday return 3, else if today is Tuesday return 5, else return 1

Answer (score 15):

That will return `3` if it's currently Monday (and the locale is such that the day is rendered as "Monday"), and `1` otherwise.

`DECODE(a, b,c, d,e, f,g, ..., h)` will compare `a` to `b`, `d`, `f`, etc., in turn. If `a` is `b`, then `DECODE` returns `c`; if `a` is `d`, then `DECODE` returns `e`; and so on. If `a` is not any of these, then `DECODE` returns `h`. (The `h` is optional; the default return-value, if `h` is not given, is `NULL`.)

Answer (score 1):

Below is explanation by parts:

> SYSDATE

is returning server date like 15-APR-19 and format based on local

> to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')

is converting into string and return week day like Monday for date 15-APR-19

> TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day'))

is removing empty spaces before and after of

Decode function is similar to if else statements and hence it simplifies code. For Current example if we write in SQL then it should be like below:

```
CASE 
  WHEN TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')) = 'Monday'  THEN '3'
  WHEN TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')) = 'Tuesday' THEN '4'
  ELSE '1' 
END
```

For complete reference see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm